# Unity Android Game Issue With Tablets

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, tablet, screen-resolution, screen-size

I am working on 2D android game in unity (portrait view).
I am using following code to scale my game scene to fit all screens and **it worked with all mobiles**

```
void Start()
{
    float targetaspect = 9.0f / 16.0f;

    // determine the game window's current aspect ratio
    float windowaspect = (float)Screen.width / (float)Screen.height;

    // current viewport height should be scaled by this amount
    float scaleheight = windowaspect / targetaspect;

    // obtain camera component so we can modify its viewport
    Camera camera = GetComponent<Camera>();

    // if scaled height is less than current height, add letterbox
    if (scaleheight < 1.0f)
    {
        Rect rect = camera.rect;

        rect.width = 1.0f;
        rect.height = scaleheight;
        rect.x = 0;
        rect.y = (1.0f - scaleheight) / 2.0f;

        camera.rect = rect;
    }
    else // add pillarbox
    {
        float scalewidth = 1.0f / scaleheight;

        Rect rect = camera.rect;

        rect.width = scalewidth;
        rect.height = 1.0f;
        rect.x = (1.0f - scalewidth) / 2.0f;
        rect.y = 0;

        camera.rect = rect;
    }

}
```

But when I tested my game **on tablet** it fit perfectly in height but in case of width, **game view width was shorter than the tablet screen width**. There was a black area seen on both sides of tablets.

**Note: according to the above code, game view get scaled to the size 480X854.**

Thank you for showing interest in my query!!!

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what your code says it's doing. See the "add pillarbox" comment. This script is ensuring you always see 9:16 aspect ratio by adding empty space where the device isn't 9:16.

You likely haven't seen a problem on phones because so many smartphones use the 16:9 aspect ratio (9:16 portrait) which exactly matches the base aspect ratio in this script. Many tables are more squared (4:3 for iPad) so tablets are more likely to show boxing. Devices wider than 16:9 will show letterboxing.

If you don't want the letterboxing and pilarboxing effect then don't use this script!

Design your game UI so it doesn't depend on a single aspect ratio. Unity UI has built in support for this. See [CanvasScaler](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html) and the flexible [layout options](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIBasicLayout.html) provided by [RectTransform](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RectTransform.html) for example.